# Cannot Navigate Object with Constraints

Tags: armature, bones, camera, constraints

I'm trying to connect the camera to follow a character movement, and I was also trying to figure out how to follow it with a constraint while in navigation mode/Walk mode, but it gives me an error message saying, *Cannot Navigate Object with Constraints*.

[image]

Is there any workaround, or something I can do to fix it?

Comment: walk/fly navigation doesn't work if your camera has constraints on it, does it have constraints like "track to" or something? In that case, all you can do is only use G/move your camera in your 3D space (if you are using the track to as I said, you can't even rotate your camera manually) .... workaround would be to disable it for a moment, move camera with walk navigation to new point and enable constraint again

Comment: @MikoCG I was using child of constraint, and Idk if there's a way I can move with walk navigation since doing normal navigation is tedious since I'm trying to have the camera track the movement while also looking another way as well. Idk if there's a way to effectively achieve this. If there is, please let me know.